# What is System.Aggregate Exception in Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Recently, (3 days ago) I started working on a new project - Bus Booking App using Blazor. I have created two tables in my database and linked them together with a foreign key. I got stuck when I run the project.

Instead of seeing the interface i created, it was an error message as shown below:

```
System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed 
(Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Microsoft.AspNetC
ore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Microsoft.AspNetCo
re.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 
'BusBookingApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6[Microsoft.
AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,BusBookingApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext,Syst
em.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1[System.String],Mi
crosoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserLogin`1[System.String],Microsoft.AspN
etCore.Identity.IdentityUserToken`1[System.String]]'.) (Error while 
validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Ide
ntityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.Ide
ntityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 
'BusBookingApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserOnlyStore`6[Microsoft.
AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser,BusBookingApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext,Syst
em.String,Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUserClaim`1
```

Please, what can i do to resolve the issue.

Comment: You should share the code that raise the exception. Otherwise it is very hard to help you.

Comment: If you get this it means you used `.Wait()` or `.Result` instead of `await`. This should be fixed to begin with. The inner exceptions show that the DI container couldn't find the `BusBookingApp.Data.ApplicationDbContext`, which in turn, means it wasn't registered in Startup.cs. What does your `Startup.cs` look like? What does the code that threw this exception look like?

Comment: Did you forget to register the DbContext with AddDbContext perhaps?

Comment: Could you share your Startup.cs?Try to register your ApplicationDbContext like this:`services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

Comment: Please, How do I share the requested file (Startup.cs) with you on this platform?